# how to show datetime in textbox in php

Tags: php, mysqli

When i update value of datetime but none show this.

edit.php:-

```
<label>Attendance Date &nbsp;</label>
<?php 
        if (!empty($f_edit_student['date_added'])) { 
        $explodeImd = explode(" " ,$f_edit_student['date_added']);
        $date = $explodeImd[0];
        }
        ?>  
        <input type="datetime-local" value= "<?php echo $date; ?>"/>
```

update.php:-

```
$student_no = $_POST['student_no'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$middlename = $_POST['middlename'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$course = $_POST['course'];
$section = $_POST['section'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$udate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$conn->query("UPDATE `student` SET `student_no` = '$student_no', `firstname` = '$firstname', `middlename` = '$middlename', `lastname` = '$lastname', `course` = '$course', `section` = '$section', `status` = '$status', `date_added` = '$udate' WHERE `student_id` = '$_REQUEST[student_id]'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: print_r($explodeImd); what it returns?

Comment: what is the value of this var `$f_edit_student` ?

Comment: @MohitKumar i m  getting value after print_r which is  Array ( [0] => 2019-09-05 [1] => 12:52:08 )

Comment: @Mohammad  $q_edit_student = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `student_id` = '$_REQUEST[student_id]'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
 $f_edit_student = $q_edit_student->fetch_array();

Comment: what you want to insert only date or both?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to use `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` in your code as it could leak sensitive information.

Comment: use now(); function

Comment: at the time edit you get date or not?

Comment: @Dharman Yes i know this is the pdo form but short form i use

Comment: at the time edit you get date or not or the problem is in updating ?

Comment: @MohitKumar only datetime show in textbox

Comment: your problem is in updating it?

Comment: @MohitKumar yes, when i edit both value then i see that date is showing and not updating

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use edit query :

```
$udate = $_POST['udate'];

    $conn->query("UPDATE `student` SET `student_no` = '$student_no', `firstname` = '$firstname', `middlename` = '$middlename', `lastname` = '$lastname', `course` = '$course', `section` = '$section', `status` = '$status', `date_added` = '$udate' WHERE `student_id` = " . $_REQUEST['student_id']) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199215/discussion-on-answer-by-manoj-singh-how-to-show-datetime-in-textbox-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to store the current date time just use MYSQL's functions.

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `student` (`date_added`) VALUES (now())");
```

Comment: But i use this $udate  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$conn->query("INSERT INTO `student` (`student_no`, `firstname`, `middlename`, `lastname`, `course`, `section`, `status`, `date_added`) VALUES($student_no, '$firstname', '$middlename', '$lastname', '$course', '$section', '$status', '$udate')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

Comment: this would assume that both webserver and mysql server are same and have same date and time configured.

Comment: Here i get update value of date.                                              
         <label>Attendance Date &nbsp;</label>
   <?php 
            if (!empty($f_edit_student['date_added'])) { 
   $explodeImd = explode(" " ,$f_edit_student['date_added']);
   $date = $explodeImd[0];
   }
   ?>  
   <input type="date" name = "attendencedate" value= "<?php echo $date; ?>"/>

Comment: but does not get time